# Do I get a new stamp every time I come to the US even if it's inside the last time period?

Tags: visas, usa, repeat-visits, us-visa-waiver-program

I recently flew to the US from the UK under the VWP, I stayed for a month between 29th April and 29th May, my stamp is good until the 29th July, however I intend to fly back early July and stay until Mid-August.

Will I be given a new stamp in my passport for another 3 months or have to exit before the 29th July?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get a new entry stamp in your passport.

The new stamp will show how long you've been admitted for this time.

Usually this will be 90 days, but the officer who admits you can decide to admit you only for the remainder of your original stay, if he considers that you're trying to live in the US under the VWP and just doing "visa runs" to reset your limit. That is quite unlikely to happen when you've been outside the US for a month, though.

(Note that the rules can also be read as saying that on each entry you *must* either be given 3 months or refused entry under the VWP. I am not aware of good evidence that they're being administered that way in practice, though).

Comment: The officer can only admit the traveler under the remainder of the original admission if the traveler has been in Canada, the Caribbean, or Mexico.